# ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 3 requests outstanding when connection from node

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to do some operations using RDD.map and it works in spark yarn. However, it produces errors when adding a `for` loop to it. I want to know **why** *and* **how to fix it**.

When I add `for (walkCount...)`, spark produces the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/xxx/usr/hadoop-2.7.3/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/xxx/appcache/application_1554174196597_0019/blockmgr-ac0eb809-641a-437a-a2f0-223084771848/1f/temp_shuffle_303f490a-6e1b-46a2-ae98-3e3460218bbf
>   (Too many open files)
>
> ...
>
> 19/04/02 19:41:53 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 3
>   requests outstanding when connection from node6/ip:40762 is closed
>   19/04/02 19:41:53 INFO RetryingBlockFetcher: Retrying fetch (1/3) for
>   1 outstanding blocks af ...

The code is below. It works without `for (walkCount...)`.

```
def randomWalk(): RDD[Array[Long]]=  {//get a sequence of nodes(Long type) from a multilayer graph    
  var randomWalk = initialWalk.map { case (nodeId, clickNode) =>
    ...
    (nodeId, pathBuffer, layer)//nodeId:Long;pathBuffer:ArrayBuffer[Long];layer:Int
  }.persist(persistLevel)//this part is no problem

  for (walkCount <- 0 until 60) {//without this for loop, it works

    randomWalk  = randomWalk.map { case (nodeId, pathBuffer, layer) =>
      val prevNodeId = pathBuffer(pathBuffer.length - 2)//the last two node
      val currentNodeId = pathBuffer.last//the last node
      (s"$prevNodeId $currentNodeId", (nodeId, pathBuffer, layer))
    }.join(indexedEdges).map { case (edge, ((nodeId, pathBuffer, currentLayer), dstNeighbors)) =>//indexedEdges is RDD[(s"$prevNodeId $currentNodeId", dstNeighbors(currentNodeId's neighbors))]
      try {
        //dstNeighbors:Array[(neighborId:Long, layer:Int, weight:Double, tal:Double)]
        val lastNode = pathBuffer.last
        val nextNode = Graphops.produceNode(dstNeighbors, currentLayer, lastNode)//Array[(nextNodeId:Long, newLayer:Int)], size is 1; choose next node, also consider whether changes layer, this function involves math.random and a constant, Graphops.q
        require(nextNode.length == 1, "nextNode.length != 1") 
        pathBuffer.append(nextNode(0)._1)
        (nodeId, pathBuffer, nextNode(0)._2)
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage)
      }
    }.persist(persistLevel)
  }//this correspond to for loop
  randomWalk.map(_._2.toArray)
}
```

Comment: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit